# Install OLE DB driver for sql server in windows docker container for fargate(AWS)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, aws-fargate

I am currently using ODBC connection for SQL server using Linux command in docker file for Fargate. Now I want to use the OLE DB driver instead of ODBC. How to install OLE DB driver in Fargate and how to connect SQL Server using OLE DB driver library in python?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.